# AWS IoT sub-things?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot, zigbee

One thing confuses me now, I have 20 Xbee motion sensors which are connected to one Xbee Gateway(Coordinator). When I connect the gateway to AWS IoT, how do I create the 20 sub-devices(things) in AWS IoT? Do I create 20 more things and put them under the parent gateway group? How do I manage the 20 motion sensors?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe different devices have different topic names?  In AWS IoT, topics will represent my sub-things?

Comment: Or adding the sensorId/Mac address (whichever works) to the MQTT json body, and create rules to indentify the correct device in with the sensorId?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best option will be create a THING_TYPE and then create all the things with this specific type, this will make easy to you manage similar things shadows, atributes e etc.

To create multiple things we can use the aws-sdk creating a thing for each item of a list using the [CreateThing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/apireference/API_CreateThing.html) method.

Or you can use the `POST /thing-registration-tasks`api method  to do a [Bulk registration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/bulk-provisioning.html).